# Corba AMI and connections management

Tags: corba

One of the main signifficant features of Corba is AMI (Asyncronous Method Invocation) in contrary of polling approach of webservices.
For example, you can implement client and 'listen' to server updates without polining server heavily (and have some delay in any case) but ruther implement callback to server updates.
This implies holding connection alive all the time, isn't it? When connection will be dropped in this case?
How does Corba manages connections?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only difference between a typical synchronous request in CORBA and an asynchronous request issued via AMI is that the client's calling thread won't be blocked until the reply arrives back from the server. There is zero difference to the server between the two approaches.

AMI in CORBA does not imply that the server can call back the client with a notification at any time. It's purely a difference in how the client behaves when making a standard two-way request to the server.

The "callback" part relates to the way the client-side asynchronicity is implemented. It requires no difference in connection management or other low-level behavior. For more information: http://www.ciaranmchale.com/corba-explained-simply/corba-messaging.html#toc78

Comment: *A server application is unaware of, and is unaffected by, how a client has made a request* is really eye-opener for me. Thanks.